# How does Hibernate determine the creation order for tables based on relationships?

Tags: java, hibernate, entity, relationship, database-schema

I would assume some sort of sorting is being done based on relationships between entities (@OneToMany, @ManyToOne, etc).  For example, Customers table needs to be created before Orders table since Customers has a OneToMany relationship with Orders and the foreign key declaration is on the Orders table.  What class is responsible for determining the creation order of tables?

******EDIT******

I found class `org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl` and in looking at the code it looks like there is no order per se, it just creates the foreign keys after all the tables are created.  Am I on the right track?

Comment: Spring Data JPA doesn't create tables, your JPA implementation does, i.e probably Hibernate or EclipseLink. You should update your question which to clarify which you are using.

Comment: I believe this is the class responsible for that: https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/boot/internal/InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java

Metadata information should be collected before creating tables; hence Although I am not an expert in such details; `InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl` should be responsible for that.